# Installing Composer to get local files of Magento

Tags: php, magento, composer-php

I have a Debian VM with a Magento 2.1.7 Installed. Now, in order to get the files in local and being able with the IDE (I use phpStorm from JetBrains) to sync the files from local to remote with a Save I need to have the Magento files too in local.

The truth is that the only path I have in sync is:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/Magento/htdocs/app
```

But anyway, having all the files and the vendor in local gives me the ability to have changes in local and not in the VM and I get organized better.

The problem comes when I want to install the Magento 2 files. I used to do `computer install` in other computers where everything was set up and all the dependencies got installed without any problem.

But in the machine I'm setting up now and I will work from now on I need to set it up.

Basically when I run composer install where I need to install the dependencies it says:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0].
    - braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for magento/framework 100.1.9 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.9].
    - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for magento/magento2-base 2.1.9 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.1.9].
    - magento/magento2-base 2.1.9 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for magento/module-shipping 100.1.3 -> satisfiable by magento/module-shipping[100.1.3].
    - magento/module-shipping 100.1.3 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.9].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - magento/module-braintree 100.1.6 requires braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0].
    - Installation request for magento/module-braintree 100.1.6 -> satisfiable by magento/module-braintree[100.1.6].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

As far as I understand and I can read, I need a php.ini in the folder which tells the composer how to get the dependencies. I haven't found the file, i found two files:

```
php.ini-production
php.ini-development
```

I imagine these two files are the ones magento use once we change the mode, so, do I need to change these 2 eventually?

How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to read the error messages, obviously you don't have php extensions not installed. also you shouldn't even change magento core files. so whatever you are doing I doubt it is what you should do.

Comment: btw. there is https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix the problem. I do know there is magento.stackexchange.com but this was more of a composer problem so I thought I could post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by modifing the `php.ini` file that I had in `C:\php.ini`. I couldn't find it earlier but once found, just get rid of the comments on the sections you need.